# AngularJS $routeProvider injection fails in directive

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, url-routing, directive

I am currently trying to get in touch with AngularJS. Since I plan to build a rather complex web application I searched for an alternative to the ngView/$routeProvider combination to be found in the ng docs as I find them quite dissatisfying for a complex application with several navigation levels.
So what I tried is to write a custom directive called `ngRoute` that could be used like this:

```
<div ng-route="users">
    <div ng-route=":id"></div>
    <div ng-route></div><!-- default -->
</div>
```

What I currently have is the following directive definition:

```
angular.module('app').directive('ngRoute', function($routeProvider) {
    var getRoute = function($el) {
        var parts = [];
        var $curEl = $el;
        while($curEl.length > 0) {
            parts.unshift($curEl.attr('ng-route'));
            $curEl = $curEl.parent().closest('*[ng-route]');
        }
        return parts.join('/');
    }

    var directiveDef = {
            link: function(scope, $el, iAttrs, controller) {
                var route = getRoute($el);
                // Register route observer dependant on calculated route...
            }
    };
    return directiveDef;
});
```

Unfortunately, I get an error due to the DI of the `$routeProvider` which I need for the registration of the route observation:

```
Error: Unknown provider: appProvider <- app <- ngRouteDirective
```

Did I miss something here? Also, feel free to critisize my approach (maybe someone already found a better solution for my problem).

Comment: Unfortunately, ngRoute is being used by Angular as of v1.1.6. They are breaking out the routing into its own module, much like ngResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the router of the angular-ui project (http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
I find it to be quite satsifying
Unfortunately, I still have no clue why my DI did not work properly

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'm not too clear about the approach but shouldn't the dependancy injection be:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('ngRoute',['$routeProvider, function($routeProvider) {
   // etc,etc...
     };
   ]);
```

Comment: I tried that notation as well but it failed the same way which I think is correct as according to the ng docs both notations are equivalent.

Comment: I ended up using the router of the angular-ui project
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
I would have answered my question but for some reason the "Answer"-button causes an error...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well using Angular version 1.2.7 (latest as of posting date). 
Jumping over to ui-router is tempting but I thought I would offer a work around (albeit a little hacky) that I have working and is stable.

First set up routes as usual, but add $routeProvider to your application:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/a/route/here', {action:"someAction"}).
  otherwise({redirectTo:'index'});
app.routeProvider = $routeProvider;
```

});

Then in the directive add additional routes as needed using:

```
app.routeProvider.when(...);
```

Angular adds the new routes and processes them fine when you navigate to them.